# Change package name and domain in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to change the package name in android studio but I don't know how to change it. I have package like this com.mycompany.myproject and I want to change it to com.abc.xyz. Thank you so much for your answer!

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16804093/android-studio-rename-package

Comment: please find the answer on this link. This works.
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16804093/android-studio-rename-package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16804093/android-studio-rename-package)

Answer (score 1):

Click on project setting icon and uncheck Compact Empty Middle Packages, and right click on each package Refactor->Rename

here are the screen short.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have my own way of doing that. I simply created a new package, and then copied all the classes in the old one to it.